# get state from redux react component in jest unit test

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, jestjs

It seems like you can't test state in react components once you make them connected components. Anyone know why? To illustrate the point, I have a test for a react component that passes without redux and fails as soon as you make it connected.

```
// MyComponent.jsx
import React from 'react'

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      foo: 'bar'
    };
  }

    render() {
    return <div></div>
  }
}

export default MyComponent
```

Here is the passing test:

```
// MyComponent.test.js
import React from 'react'
import MyComponent from '../src/components/MyComponent'
import { mount } from 'enzyme'

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  describe('interactions', () => {
    let wrapper
    beforeEach(() => {
      wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />)
    })

    it('foo to equal bar', () => {
      expect(wrapper.state().foo).toEqual('bar')
    })
  })
})
```

Now I'm introducing Redux and connecting the component:

```
// MyComponent.jsx

...

export default connect(function (state){
  return {
    currentUser: state.currentUser
  }
})(MyComponent);
```

And here is the updated test:

```
// MyComponent.test.js
import React from 'react'
import MyComponent from '../src/components/MyComponent'
import { mount } from 'enzyme'

import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store'

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  const state = {}
  const mockStore = configureStore()

  describe('interactions', () => {
    let wrapper
    beforeEach(() => {
      wrapper = mount(<MyComponent store={ mockStore(state) } />)
    })

    it('foo to equal bar', () => {
      expect(wrapper.state().foo).toEqual('bar')
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend just exporting both the `connect()` (the default export) and the actual component itself.

This way you can test the component separately outside of the connected version of the component.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      foo: 'bar'
    };
  }

    render() {
    return <div></div>
  }
}

export MyComponent

export default connect(function (state){
  return {
    currentUser: state.currentUser
  }
})(MyComponent);
```

and then the test:

```
import { MyComponent } from '../src/components/MyComponent'
import { mount } from 'enzyme'

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  describe('interactions', () => {
    let wrapper
    beforeEach(() => {
      wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />)
    })

    it('foo to equal bar', () => {
      expect(wrapper.state().foo).toEqual('bar')
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Good solution - I would add just for clarity that I think you need to add export in-front of class MyComponent right?

Comment: @SpencerBigum You could do that, you'll notice that I am exporting the component on a separate line right after the component and before the `connect()`. Both work.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `connect()` generates a wrapper component that manages the store interaction process.  In your second snippet, `<MyComponent>` is now the component generated by `connect()`, not your original component.  You would need to dig another level of nesting deeper in the render hierarchy to check on the contents of the real component's state.